# Babel-loader stops transpiling arrow functions after including a 3rd party library

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs, babel-loader

I'm using `Webpack` and `babel-loader` and `lit-element` for my project.

`lit-element` package is distributed as es2015 module and it needs to be transpiled. Otherwise, it gives me an error in the browser `Class constructor lit_element_LitElement cannot be invoked without 'new'`

Since it's in `/node_modules/` folder I need to explicitly include it like so.

```
{
  test: /\.js$/,
  exclude: /node_modules/,
  include: [/node_modules(?:\/|\\)lit-element|lit-html/],
  loader: 'babel-loader'
},
```

It solves the problem, but for some reason it prevents arrow functions from being transpiled. In other words, arrow syntax is not replaced neither in `lit-element` package nor in my app code.

Here's a snippet from `package.json`

```
"@babel/core": "^7.4.3",
"@babel/preset-env": "^7.4.3",
"babel-loader": "^8.0.5",
```

Here's `babelrc` file

```
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-env"
  ]
}
```

What am I missing?